# edit canvas pixel coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

Using canvas js, how can one edit canvas pixel coordinates?
Tried

```
var pixelData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var length = pixelData.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {

        pixelData.data[i] = pixelData.data[i] * ratio;
        pixelData.data[i + 1] = pixelData.data[i + 1] * ratio;
        pixelData.data[i + 2] = pixelData.data[i + 2] * ratio;
    }
    console.log(pixelData);
    context.putImageData(pixelData, 0, 0);
```

It changes pixel's color. But coordinates change is needed

Comment: You want to move them according to what rule? The simplest if you want to move them all in the same direction is to use the *x* and *y* parameters if `ctx.putImageData(ImageData, x, y)`

Comment: I want to move them according to algorithm. Unfortunately putImageData(ImageData, x, y) is very slow

Comment: The slowest is getImageData, and I don't see how you add back your imageData's pixels on the context faster than with `putImageData`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate position into a buffer using coordinates doing (byte array):

```
pos = (y * width + x) << 2;    // << 2 = x4 but slightly faster + forces integer
```

or Uint32 array which require you to write a single pixel using a 32-bit value:

```
pos = y * width + x
```

If you need to use a bitmap approach instead of using paths, you can obtain the entire bitmap in a single operation, draw the pixels onto that bitmap and finally "commit" back to canvas, also in a single operation. For this it would be advisable to write wrappers:

```
function getBitmap(ctx) {
  let idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  return {
    imageData: idata,
    buffer32 : new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer)    // just a view/reference
  }
}
```

And to commit:

```
function commit(ctx, bitmap) {
  ctx.putImageData(bitmap.imageData, 0, 0)
}
```

Then to set a pixel you could use something like this (example written for readability):

```
function setPixel(bitmap, x, y, r, g, b, a = 255) {  // = 255 for ES6 code, remove otherwise
  let pixel = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;        // make 32-bit value of ABGR
  let pos = (y * bitmap.imageData.width + x)|0;      // calc. position, force integer
  bitmap.buffer32[pos] = pixel;                      // set pixel in buffer
}
```

The reason for all this is not just structure, but you can easily rewrite the functions later to do path operations instead.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const r = Math.random;  // just to simplify example loop

// obtain the bitmap
const bmp = getBitmap(ctx);

// draw something
for(let i = 0, ra = 300; i < 21; i += 0.01) {
  setPixel(
    bmp,                       // bitmap
    (160+ra*Math.cos(i))|0,    // x
    (100+ra*Math.sin(i))|0,    // y
    255*r(), 255*r(), 255*r()  // r, g, b [,a]
  );
  ra *= 0.997;
}

// commit changes
commit(ctx, bmp);

function getBitmap(ctx) {
  let idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  return {
    imageData: idata,
    buffer32 : new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer)    // just a view/reference
  }
}

function commit(ctx, bitmap) {
  ctx.putImageData(bitmap.imageData, 0, 0)
}

function setPixel(bitmap, x, y, r, g, b, a = 255) {  // = 255 for ES6 code, remove otherwise
  let pixel = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;        // make 32-bit value of ABGR
  let pos = (y * bitmap.imageData.width + x)|0;      // calc. position, force integer
  bitmap.buffer32[pos] = pixel;                      // set pixel in buffer
}
```

```css
#c {border:1px solid; background:#000}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=320 height=320></canvas>
```

Alternatively you could use path approach as mentioned earlier but this can only draw one color at one time unless you want to fill each pixel directly which can be slower than filling all at once:

```
ctx.beginPath();

// draw all pixels here using integer positions for x and y
ctx.rect(x, y, 1, 1);

// and finally fill in current fill style
ctx.fill();
```

Or if you need each pixel drawn directly;

```
ctx.fillStyle = pixelColor;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```